# Where was Godzilla lying dormant for all this time?

Tags: godzilla-2014, monsterverse

If Godzilla was dormant for all this time, where was he lying dormant?

It is not as if he is a brown bear hiding in a cave, where was he been hiding all this time for humans not to be able to find him?

[image]

Comment: Might have just chilling in the sea, humans have only explored a small percentage of the Oceans on Earth, so he could've easily  stayed hidden. (This requires him to have gills, and I don't remember whether or not he does)

Comment: @Edlothiad, didn't know he could breath under water?

Comment: Doesn't he come out of the water in the film?

Comment: I agree. Underwater.

Comment: The real tragedy of Godzilla is that [we had the means to persuade him/her to stay there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GC_mV1IpjWA).

Answer (score 3):

The film's [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18594685-godzilla---the-official-movie-novelization) suggests that Godzilla was chilling in the deep ocean until some idiot in a submarine came and annoyed it. The US, French and British authorities evidently tried to kill it with nukes but failed.

> “In 1954,” he began, “the first time a nuclear submarine ever reached
> the lowest depths, it awakened something.”
>
> “The Americans first thought it was the Russians,” Graham added. “The
> Russians thought that it was the Americans. All those nuclear tests in
> the Pacific? Not tests…”
>
> “They were trying to kill it.” Serizawa indicated the ancient film
> footage from the 1950s. “Him.”
>
> Ford’s jaw dropped. Breaking eye contact with Serizawa, he looked more
> closely at the projected images of the 1954 A-bomb detonation, the
> bomb with the cartoon lizard inscribed on its cone, a mushroom cloud
> rising over the once-tranquil Pacific Ocean, and, finally, impossibly,
> the grainy silhouette of a titanic beast rising up from the sea, a row
> of jagged fins dimly visible along its spine.
>
> “An ancient alpha predator,” Serizawa explained.
>
> “Millions of years older than mankind,” Graham said, “from a time when
> the Earth was ten times more radioactive than it is today. The
> animal—and others like it—consumed that radiation as a food source.
> But as radiation levels on the surface naturally subsided, these
> creatures adapted to live deeper in the oceans, farther underground,
> absorbing radiation from the planet’s core. The organization we work
> for, Monarch, was established in the wake of this discovery. A
> multinational organization, formed in secrecy, to search for him,
> study him, learn everything we could.”

It remained largely hidden in the depths of the ocean, growing fat on enormous portions of whale and squid meat until one of the MUTO spores hatched at which point it came out of the water and went a'wanderin'

> “Doctor, are we certain this is the same animal from sixty years ago?”
>
> Serizawa suspected as much. “Remains were never found,” he reminded
> the admiral. “But if the MUTO is his prey,” Graham began, calling
> Serizawa’s attention back to the printout of the wave pattern Joe
> Brody had detected, “this signal shows a call. Why call up a
> predator?”
>
> Stenz and others present threw out possible explanations, with even
> Martinez chiming in with something about echoes or audio distortions,
> but Serizawa no longer had any doubts or questions. There seemed only
> one obvious conclusion. “It didn’t,” he said solemnly. “The predator
> was only listening. The MUTO was calling something else.” His
> reasoning led him to another ominous hypothesis. “The pattern,” he
> addressed Graham urgently. “Focus our search on Nevada.”

In the newest Godzilla film (*[King of the Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla:_King_of_the_Monsters_(2019_film))*) Doctor Rick Stanton posits that he's able to use an underground tunnel system that reaches into the hollow core of the Earth. That would certainly explain why he's not been seen on the surface, especially if the tunnels were, until recently, relatively enclosed.

> **Dr Rick:** *He dropped off the scan near Venezuela.*
>
> **Chandler:** *Dropped off?*
>
> **Dr. Rick:** *I'm telling you, Dr. Brooks was right. It's a Hollow Earth. That's how he moves around so fast, using these underwater tunnels like wormholes.*

Answer (score 0):

The marinas trench he can dive incredibly deep and it makes sense because we can’t go down that deep long enough to look around

Comment: Do you have any evidence you could [edit] in to back this up? For example, is there anywhere confirming this or are you just speculating?

Comment: Err. We've gone down and had a look around. Both with robots and, on several occasions, with people.